# R, want a rotatable 3d plot, given a list x,y; z = count of each different supplied x,y

Tags: r, plot

I have a CSV of x,y data, I want to plot them but use the z axis to display the count of each different x,y combination.

NOTE: CSV is sorted so y > x hence no duplication on the graph

I have the x,y graph

```
fwc <- read.csv(file="resultsort.csv",head=FALSE,sep=",")
plot( fwc , xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 10))
```

I've found

```
vis.supstat.com/categories.html
```

just struggling with the z = count(x,y) bit

ColinDNZ

Answer (score 0):

The count part is easily handled with either `table` or `xtabs`.

```
xtabs( ~ x+y, data=fwc)
```

The rotate-able plot would be handled by the functions in the rgl package:

```
install.packages("rgl")
library("rgl")
help(pack="rgl")
```

Perhaps:

```
plot3d( xtabs( ~ x+y, data=fwc) )
```

You didn't say what kind of plot you wanted. I hope it's not one of those Excel pseudo-3d barcharts.